# How to buffer stdout in memory and write it from a dedicated thread

Tags: c, file, stdout, buffering

I have a C application with many worker threads.  It is essential that these do not block so where the worker threads need to write to a file on disk, I have them write to a circular buffer in memory, and then have a dedicated thread for writing that buffer to disk.

The worker threads do not block any more.  The dedicated thread can safely block while writing to disk without affecting the worker threads (it does not hold a lock while writing to disk).  My memory buffer is tuned to be sufficiently large that the writer thread can keep up.

This all works great.  My question is, how do I implement something similar for stdout?

I could macro printf() to write into a memory buffer, but I don't have control over all the code that might write to stdout (some of it is in third-party libraries).

Thoughts?
NickB

Comment: All of the solutions here are wrong, because writing to pipes can block. (And if you set them nonblocking, the `FILE` will just get in an unrecoverable error state if it would block when it needs to flush.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I like the idea of using `freopen`.  You might also be able to redirect `stdout` to a pipe using [dup](http://mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/dup.3.asp) and [dup2](http://mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/dup2.3.asp), and then use `read` to grab data from the pipe.

Something like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LEN 40

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  char buffer[MAX_LEN+1] = {0};
  int out_pipe[2];
  int saved_stdout;

  saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);  /* save stdout for display later */

  if( pipe(out_pipe) != 0 ) {          /* make a pipe */
    exit(1);
  }

  dup2(out_pipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);   /* redirect stdout to the pipe */
  close(out_pipe[1]);

  /* anything sent to printf should now go down the pipe */
  printf("ceci n'est pas une pipe");
  fflush(stdout);

  read(out_pipe[0], buffer, MAX_LEN); /* read from pipe into buffer */

  dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);  /* reconnect stdout for testing */
  printf("read: %s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I tried an approach like this, I found `read` hangs if there is nothing in the pipe.  But adding `long flags = fcntl(out_pipe[0], F_GETFL); flags |= O_NONBLOCK; fcntl(out_pipe[0], F_SETFL, flags);` to the init section fixed that problem.

Comment: Nice method, but how to somethink simmilar in Windows?

Comment: @NateKohl Hey Nate, great code, can you please provide an example for two different functions one reads the output of the other and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have however a followup question. When I run the print statements in a child process which I have created via fork. I always get a 1 at the end of the string I read. Do you know where this comes from?

Answer (score 9):

If you're working with the GNU libc, you might use <s>[memory streams](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_228.html)</s> [string streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html).

Comment: This I think is the real right answer.  The pipe approach involves expensive system calls and is certainly going to block.

Comment: The link has expired, use this instead https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html.

Answer (score 4):

You can "redirect" `stdout` into file using `freopen()`.

`man freopen` says:

> The freopen() function opens the file
>   whose name is the string  pointed to
>   by path and associates the stream
>   pointed to by stream with it.  The
>   original stream (if it exists) is
>   closed.  The mode  argument  is  used
>   just  as  in  the  fopen()  function. 
>   The primary use of the freopen()
>   function is to change the file
>   associated with a standard  text 
>   stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout).

This file well could be a pipe - worker threads will write to that pipe and writer thread will listen.

Comment: This does not solve my problem.  I am trying to move the disk writing off of the thread making the printf() call.  Using freopen() would still have my printf() calls writing to a file, albeit a different file to stdout.  Is it possible for me to specify a "file" to freopen() which is not a disk file?

Comment: Sure. Use pipe instead of file.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you wrap your entire application in another? Basically, what you want is a smart `cat` that copies stdin to stdout, buffering as necessary. Then use standard stdin/stdout redirection. This can be done without modifying your current application at all.

```
~MSalters/# YourCurrentApp | bufcat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change how buffering works with `setvbuf()` or `setbuf()`. There's a description here: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/input_and_output.html.

[Edit]

`stdout` really is a `FILE*`. If the existing code works with `FILE*`s, I don't see what prevents it from working with `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution ( for both things your doing ) would be to use a gathering write via [writev](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev).

Each thread could for example sprintf into a iovec buffer and then pass the iovec pointers to the writer thread and have it simply call writev with stdout.

Here is an example of using writev from [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/ex/writev_8c-source.html)

Under Windows you would use WSAsend for similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The method using the 4096 bigbuf will only sort of work.  I've tried this code, and while it does successfully capture stdout into the buffer, it's unusable in a real world case.  You have no way of knowing how long the captured output is, so no way of knowing when to terminate the string '\0'.  If you try to use the buffer you get 4000 characters of garbage spit out if you had successfully captured 96 characters of stdout output.

In my application, I'm using a perl interpreter in the C program.  I have no idea how much output is going to be spit out of what ever document is thrown at the C program, and hence the code above would never allow me to cleanly print that output out anywhere.

Comment: If you fill the bigbuf with zeros first, then you are guaranteed that the string will be null terminated ... unless the last byte of bigbuf is not a zero. But in that case, you can detect an overflow.