# Cin doesn't pause for input, despite using both cin.clear() and cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, cin

This input is redirected from file to the executable in a unix terminal:

```
10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
5 10 20 30 40 50
```

Cin doesn't wait for input even though it seems to be in a good state to do so.

```
int main(void) {
    std::cout << "GOOD: " << std::cin.good() << std::endl
              << "EOF: " << std::cin.eof() << std::endl
              << "FAIL: " << std::cin.fail() << std::endl
              << "BAD: " << std::cin.bad() << "\n\n";
    int s;
    while(std::cin >> s) {
            int * arr = new int[s];
            for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                    std::cin >> arr[i];
                    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n\n";
            delete[] arr;
    }

    std::cout << "CAN READ: " << (bool)(std::cin >> s) << std::endl
              << "GOOD: "<< std::cin.good() << std::endl
              << "EOF: "<< std::cin.eof() << std::endl
              << "FAIL: "<< std::cin.fail() << std::endl
              << "BAD: "<< std::cin.bad() << "\n\n";

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);

    std::cout << "GOOD: " << std::cin.good() << std::endl
              << "EOF: " << std::cin.eof() << std::endl
              << "FAIL: " << std::cin.fail() << std::endl
              << "BAD: " << std::cin.bad() << "\n\n";

    std::cin.clear();

    std::cout << "GOOD: " << std::cin.good() << std::endl
              << "EOF: " << std::cin.eof() << std::endl
              << "FAIL: " << std::cin.fail() << std::endl
              << "BAD: " << std::cin.bad() << "\n\n";

    std::cout << "Enter a #:\n";
    std::cin >> s; // unable to provide input (EDIT: from keyboard) here
    std::cout << s << std::endl; 

    std::cout << "Program ends.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
GOOD: 1
EOF: 0
FAIL: 0
BAD: 0

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

10 20 30 40 50

CAN READ: 0
GOOD: 0
EOF: 1
FAIL: 1
BAD: 0

GOOD: 0
EOF: 1
FAIL: 0
BAD: 0

GOOD: 1
EOF: 0
FAIL: 0
BAD: 0

Enter a #:
5
Program ends.
```

What am I missing here? Why doesn't cin allow me to provide it input even though its buffer is empty and the stream is in a good state? What can I do to get cin to accept further input here?

Comment: cin is redirected to file... How do you want to provide the input from file when it was read till the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought it was possible to seamlessly obtain keyboard input after redirecting a file to cin (thanks to Artemy Vysotsky for helping me realize that this is not the case).

For anyone that has a similar problem, std::cin.rdbuf() can be used. Details here: [Can std::cin switch from accepting file input to keyboard input at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625956/can-stdcin-switch-from-accepting-file-input-to-keyboard-input-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

use cin.flush(); after taking input an integer. It will flush the stream and you can take the string input again.
If you want to know why it happens you can read it [here](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/75206-cin-not-allowing-input-after-first-use-function.html)