# C/C++ Save console output in variable

Tags: c, variables, console, output, popen

I want to save the output of a system command in a variable, to use it for a GTKLabel.

I know that I can use popen to record the output like this:

```c
FILE *in;
extern FILE *popen();
char buff[512];
char test[512];

if(!(in = popen("adb devices", "r"))){
   exit(1);
}

while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
    printf("%s", buff);
}

pclose(in);
```

So now, it does only print the Output, but I want to save it into a varible. How do i do that? Thanks in Advance community!

Comment: What do you want to save into a variable? Also, include the header `stdio.h` which contains the prototype of `popen`. You should not declare a prototype of standard library functions yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout, though that has some C++ solutions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use output redirection for this. It works perfectly in command line, and should work good in a program as well.

```
$ program > outputfile
```

This will record the output of the `program` to the file `outputfile`. You can later read this using normal `fopen` command. (The dollar is the linux prompt.)

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what you mean. Where do i have do put this in my Code/Terminal? When I type this into a terminal it just says:

    program: command not found