# Is it possible to read STDOUT before redirection?

Tags: c++, linux, stdout

I am trying to read from STDOUT in C++ but every example I find implies using `pipe` and `dup` and I wonder if is there a way to avoid them. Let's say just:

```
cout << "Hello world" << endl;

/* ... */

read(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, MAX_LEN)
```

Comment: Why would you want to read STDOUT? It is an output channel intended for writing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Redirecting STDOUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout) — Particularly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6211644/1241334) to that question.

Comment: but - instead of `cout` - why not stream to a `ostringstream` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't read from `STDOUT_FILENO`. The call to [`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) will always return `EBADF` because `STDOUT_FILENO` is not valid to read from. That is why people use `pipe` and `dup`.

---

If you're looking for a more C++ approach to what I think you want to do, check out the answer to: [How to redirect cin and cout to files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files) If you replace `std::cout`'s output buffer with something of your own creation, you can manipulate it however you want. Unfortunately, this will only capture output operations to `std::cout` and not things like direct calls to `write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)`, `printf(...)` and whatnot. It is also way more inconvenient (in my experience).