# Is it possible to replace the whole line with #define?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Let's assume that I have a program with many files and many `cout`'s, and for debug purposes I would like to disable output for a moment, but only in a single file.

**It is just out of curiosity question, I know that I shouldn't do that to disable output, but I started to wonder when facing this problem, and it only shows properly what I mean.**

I tried to create a `#define` macro, but I can't replace the whole line, only a single symbol (with params).

For example:

```
//some common header file
#ifdef DISABLE_OUTPUT
#define cout... void; //?? DK exactly what should i put here
#endif
```

```
//other file
#include "commons.h" //my macro
#define DISABLE_OUTPUT

void foo()
{
    ...
    cout << "blablabla" << 4 << "something" << endl; // should be removed
    ...
}
```

If `DISABLE_OUTPUT` is defined, the whole line should be replaced with `void;` (better clear the line).

The problem is that I don't know how to clear the whole line with `#define`.

Is there any "magic" symbol or trick that I can use?

Comment: Make a object of a dummy class, which has `operator<<()` overloaded (which does nothing) and make `#define cout NAME_OF_THE_DUMMY_OBJECT`, something like: https://ideone.com/kv381z

Comment: The actual question si: "_Why_ do you want to use a macro?" Don't use macros without reason. Why not use a function for the statement and a macro to call it. `void;` is invalid in both langugages C and C++. And don't double-tag questions, C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: @mch I was thinking about it, but is there any way to do that without defining the class?

Comment: Why don’t you want to define the class?

Comment: `#define cout if ( 0 ) cout` would work ... some of the time.

Comment: You may be interested in sort-of-but-not-quite duplicate question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout

Comment: @Olaf I don't want to use macro in this particular case and I've wrote that. just want to know if i can replace the whole line with #define...

Comment: Oh, this was just out of curiosity? I think a lot of people here, including myself, didn’t quite realize that and thought you intended to use this code. Curiosity is a much better reason to ask this.

Comment: @Macias: Erm … what do you think `#define` is for? A good C++ book would be a start.

Comment: @DanielH Exactly, just curiosity :) Edited now for the short-sighted

Answer (score 3):

It’s a bad idea to define a macro with the same name as a standard library component, so you shouldn’t `#define cout` at all. I’m going to assume you `#define disableable_cout` instead.

The simplest answer would be to define it like this:

```
#ifdef DISABLE_OUTPUT
#define disableable_cout if (false) cout
#else
#define disableable_cout cout
#endif
```

And then update the `cout` line in `foo` to this:

```
disableable_cout << "blablabla" << 4 << "something" << endl;
```

Which would expand to either this:

```
if (false) cout << "blablabla" << 4 << "something" << endl;
```

if `DISABLE_OUTPUT` is defined, or to this:

```
cout << "blablabla" << 4 << "something" << endl;
```

if `DISABLE_OUTPUT` were not defined.

Then, if `DISABLE_OUTPUT` is defined, the output line is skipped; if not, it will happen.

Alternately, you could require `DISABLE_OUTPUT` is always defined, to either 0 (don’t disable) or 1 (do disable). Then you could use a single definition, like this:

```
#define disableable_cout if (!DISABLE_OUTPUT) cout
```

Note that, either option is fragile, like most macros, but it should work in the typical case.

Comment: Yes i know that, 'I know that isn't a best way to do that, but its not the case.'

Comment: @Macias Even given that I thought it was worth warning about the fragility. Or do you mean my warning against declaring a macro with the same name as something in the standard library?

Comment: In this case, I think `#define DISABLE_OUTPUT` would have to be changed to either `#define DISABLE_OUTPUT 1` (or 0), or to an actual variable: `static const bool DISABLE_OUTPUT = true;` (or false).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, fair. Another option would be to keep the `#ifdef` lines, and use `if (false) cout`.