# Is there any way to view the output of stdout or stderr in Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, windows, unreal-engine4

I am using a dll that is outputting valuable debugging information, but I don't know how to view it since it isn't printed in the output log. I would like to know if there is some workaround so I can view whats being written to stdout and stderr.

Comment: this looks promising https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Use_std::cout_with_Unreal_Engine_Editor

Comment: Can you check the event log of system?

Comment: @John That unfortunately doesn't work because the program in question writes to stdout through printf. I should have clarified that though.

Comment: This gives instructions on how to redirect `stdout` to a file. I'm too sleepy to link that to unreal's stream in my head, but would the file output get you what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout

Comment: @John I'm not sure which answer you're talking about, but the top one mentions how his solution only works for cout not stdout in general. I've seen that you can use freopen though and redirect the output to a file which should work well enough for my situation.

Comment: The top answer. They redirect to `/dev/null`, but redirecting to an actual file should be the same process.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty easy (even though there is very few places explaining how).

Idea: Inherit `std::stringbuf` to make it use `UE_LOG` and then feed an instance of that inherited class to `std::cout`. E.g., something like this:

**Inherited class**

```
#include <sstream>

class LStream : public std::stringbuf{
protected:
    int sync() {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("%s"), *FString(str().c_str()));
        str("");
        return std::stringbuf::sync();
    }
};
```

**Telling `std::cout` to use `LStream`**

```
LStream Stream;
std::cout.rdbuf(&Stream); 
std::cout << "some message" << std::endl;
```

Sources:

- [Redirecting cout to UE_LOG (1)](https://nerivec.github.io/old-ue4-wiki/pages/use-stdcout-with-unreal-engine-editor.html)
- [Redirecting cout to UE_LOG (2)](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/using-std-cout-and-ue-log-get-ostream-into-output-console/370079)
- [Redirecting cout to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150468/how-to-redirect-cin-and-cout-to-files)

Comment: This solution works for std::cout but not for stdout classic printf.