# Redirect standard out from C++ to Python log file (logging module)

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, file-descriptor

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081657/how-do-i-prevent-a-c-shared-library-to-print-on-stdout-in-python/5103455), but more specifically, how can I redirect C++ standard out that is called from Python to a log file? The log file is created and written to using the python `logging` module with a `RotatingFileHandler`. Currently using Python 2.7.x.

Comment: When I wrote the answer, I missed the python 2.7 part... python 2.7 is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I will venture an answer while hoping someone suggests something better. And I am not giving code examples because it would take me time. It also depends on how you do the wrapping of C++, I guess.

If I controlled the C++ code, and it was not too big, I would replace all uses of stdout by a logging mechanism, which I could easily redirect to a function exposed from python.

If this is not possible, I would redirect stdout (all within C++) to a custom streambuffer (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout), but with a stream that writes to the function exposed from python). I would check [boost's streambuffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html).

**EDIT 1**

If you use PyBind11 to expose C++, check [capturing-standard-output-from-ostream](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/utilities.html#capturing-standard-output-from-ostream)